# How to reduce x select to 1 select?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following 3 selects and I want to improve performance, what can I do?

```
select object into lastUpdate 
from data
where predicate = '#lastUpdate' 
and subject = 'subject1';
select object into latitude
from data
where predicate = '#latitude'
and subject = 'subject1';
select object into longitude
from data
where predicate = '#longitude'
and subject = 'subject1';
```

Thank you

Comment: Looks like a [bad data model](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/entity-attribute-value-eav-design-in-postgresql-dont-do-it/).

Comment: I think it's already as good as it's going to get, given your type-less schema.

Comment: Please show us the query plans for these queries. Do you have proper indices on the table?

Comment: SELECT data.object AS LastUpdate, 
data.object AS latitude
from data as data
WHERE
data.subject = 'url1'
and data.predicate = '#lastUpdate'
AND data.predicate = '#latitude' =>It doesn't work I guess because I'm asking 2x the predicate in the same table

Comment: Index Scan using subjectetpredicate on data  (cost=0.69..12.25 rows=3 width=61) (actual time=0.091..0.092 rows=1 loops=1)   Index Cond: (((subject)::text = 'url1'::text) AND ((predicate)::text = '#lastUpdate'::text)) Planning Time: 0.171 ms Execution Time: 0.116 ms

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JOIN:

```
select lu.object, lat.object, lon.object
  into lastupdate, latitude, longitude
from data lu
  left join data lat on lat.subject = lu.subject and lat.predicate = '#latitude' 
  left join data lon on lon.subject = lu.subject and lon.predicate = '#longitude' 
where lu.subject = 'subject1'
  and lu.predicate = '#lastUpdate';
```

Comment: This is a script on a mass (an iteration of about 400,000 times) you just saved me an incredible amount of time by your help (because I also changed other requests), sincerely, thank you! (even if I still have others to improve)

Comment: I made https://dbfiddle.uk/Wv0ROVQZ your query perfectly meets my need for title, description and shortDescription (instead of latitude, longitude in this example).
How can I put everything together in your query to get title, description, shortDescription, longitude and latitude? thank you

Comment: if lu.predicate = '#lastUpdate' doesn't exist then all other queries are also null... so it's not good