# How can I improve multiple queries into one

Tags: postgresql

I want to improve the performance of these 2 queries:

```
select object into latitude  
from data
where predicate = 'latitude' 
and subject = ( select object 
                from data 
                where subject = (select object 
                                 from data 
                                  where subject = 'url1' and predicate = '#isLocatedAt') 
and predicate = 'http://schema.org/geo');

select object into Longitude  
from data 
where predicate = 'longitude' 
and subject = ( select object 
                from data 
                where subject = (select object 
                                 from data 
                                 where subject = 'url1' and predicate = '#isLocatedAt') 
and predicate = 'http://schema.org/geo');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lCFT9l5Q)

I don't have an index on data.object because it's a text and it's too big.

Explain analyse (for 1 requête):

```
QUERY PLAN
Index Scan using subjectetpredicate on data  (cost=25.19..36.76 rows=3 width=63) (actual time=34.299..34.303 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (((subject)::text = $1) AND ((predicate)::text = 'latitude'::text))
  InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
    ->  Index Scan using subjectetpredicate on data data_2  (cost=12.94..24.50 rows=3 width=63) (actual time=31.374..31.379 rows=1 loops=1)
          Index Cond: (((subject)::text = $0) AND ((predicate)::text = 'geo'::text))
          InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
            ->  Index Scan using subjectetpredicate on data data_1  (cost=0.69..12.25 rows=3 width=63) (actual time=0.329..0.332 rows=1 loops=1)
                  Index Cond: (((subject)::text = 'url1'::text) AND ((predicate)::text = '#isLocatedAt'::text))
Planning Time: 1.071 ms
Execution Time: 34.359 ms
```

Comment: It seems like you are doing some self join. Would you care to share some sample data and desired output instead of an SQL that you think is the way to go.

Comment: what performance issue do you have ? can you share the EXPLAIN ANALYSE result in your real environment ?

Comment: An obvious improvement would be not to repeat the query for the `geo` object twice. Query it once, *then* get its latitude and longitude.

Comment: precisely, I don't really know how to question him 1 x for the 2 answers, hence my post;)

Comment: Just use the same approach that was suggested for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74946605/1048572)?

Comment: It seems what you're doing is drilling two levels down in a hierarchy and then getting the values from that?

Comment: …or, given you use `SELECT … INTO` which looks like PL/pgSQL, just introduce an extra temporary variable?

Comment: The other question is for another field (I made a mistake in the naming); it concerns the descriptions

Comment: I can't simplify the 2 requests into 1 because of the 'where predicate = 'longitude' and 'where predicate = 'latitude'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query plan shows that you're doing 6 index scans sequentially. Rewrite your script so that you have to do only 4, by storing the shared result in a temporary variable:

```
select object into geolocation
--            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
from data
where predicate = 'http://schema.org/geo'
  and subject = (select object 
                 from data 
                 where predicate = '#isLocatedAt'
                   and subject = 'url1');

select object into latitude  
from data
where predicate = 'latitude' 
  and subject = geolocation;
--              ^^^^^^^^^^^

select object into longitude  
from data 
where predicate = 'longitude' 
  and subject = geolocation;
--              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can achieve the same in a single query (which doesn't necessarily make it any faster or easier to read) by using a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/queries-with.html) or simply by flipping your subqueries to get a result with multiple columns:

```
select
  (
    select object  
    from data
    where predicate = 'longitude'
      and subject = geolocation
  ), (
    select object
    from data
    where predicate = 'latitude'
      and subject = geolocation
  )
  into longitude, latitude
from (
  select object as geolocation
  from data
  where predicate = 'http://schema.org/geo'
    and subject = (select object 
                   from data 
                   where predicate = '#isLocatedAt'
                     and subject = 'url1')
) as temp;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! just with this post you taught me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nested subqueries, we can rethink this as a series of self-joins and flip it on its head. I find this much easier to understand, and it's much faster (at least on this tiny dataset).

0. url1, #isLocatedAt, y
1. y, http://schema.org/geo, z
2. z, (latitude, longitude)

To do it in a single query, filter it on `where predicate in ('latitude', 'longitude')`.

```
select
  l2.predicate, l2.object
from data l0
join data l1 on l0.object = l1.subject and l1.predicate  = 'http://schema.org/geo'
join data l2 on l1.object = l2.subject and l2.predicate in ('latitude', 'longitude')
where l0.subject = 'url1' and l0.predicate = '#isLocatedAt'
```

This is a couple orders of magnitude faster, though it would have to be run against a realistic amount of data to matter.

```
QUERY PLAN
Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..24.51 rows=1 width=548) (actual time=0.040..0.042 rows=2 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..16.34 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.022..0.023 rows=1 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (l0.object = (l1.subject)::text)
        ->  Index Scan using subjectetpredicate on data l0  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (((subject)::text = 'url1'::text) AND ((predicate)::text = '#isLocatedAt'::text))
        ->  Index Scan using predicate on data l1  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=548) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((predicate)::text = 'http://schema.org/geo'::text)
  ->  Index Scan using subjectetpredicate on data l2  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=1064) (actual time=0.017..0.018 rows=2 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((subject)::text = l1.object)
        Filter: ((predicate)::text = ANY ('{latitude,longitude}'::text[]))
Planning Time: 0.192 ms
Execution Time: 0.072 ms
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/lG5lq9Pk).

This approach is also a step towards generalizing it as a [recursive CTE](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-recursive-cte/).

---

Note that you don't need an index on `subject` because you have an index on `(subject, predicate)`.

Comment: it's about 400000 objects that I have to reconstitute. Thank you very much for your advice and for the index I thought I needed subject  and SubectAndPredicate

Comment: @Camel4488 ["*A multicolumn B-tree index can be used with query conditions that involve any subset of the index's columns, but the index is most efficient when there are constraints on the leading (leftmost) columns.*"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/indexes-multicolumn.html) Which is to say that an index on (a, b, c) can also handle `where a = 42`, and `where a = 42 and b = 23` efficiently. It can also handle `where b = 23 and c = 99` and `where c = 99` and `where a = 42 and c = 99` but much less efficiently

Comment: Ok thanks for the directions. on the other hand little last question, your request returns me 2 lines (I'm not used to it), how to take just latitude or longitude in an into for example?

Comment: @Camel4488 I'm not sure I understand. Do you have two different tables called longitude and latitude? If you want to improve performance, it would help to explain the whole problem you're solving, rather than just help with the solution.

Comment: Sorry I'm using a translation, with your solution I didn't know how to find the longitude or the latitude (because of the in)